Is it possible to prevent two buttons from stacking in the same position in MQL5?
I am a trading developer.
I am developing a GUI with mql5 and there are two tags on top. When I click on a tag, it hides the current section and shows another section. But there are two buttons (show, hide) in the same position. Here, when you click the show button, you can see that another hidden button is activated.
This seems to be because this hidden button has a higher priority than the other show button.
I need to fix this issue. Please help!
When you click any button, the button marked as expected will work without priority.
